# How to select a datatable row using cell value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

The Goal is to select a row in jQuery Datatable using a cell value. 
Maybe like `document.getelementbyvalue` 
or with a jquery function.

As an example I want to search the content of searchvalue in column id and select the row which contains the content of the variable searchvalue.

The datatable is a jQuery datatable which is filled by mdata.

Here is the code:

```
var searchvalue = null;

function ()
    {       
    var processURL="path";
    $.ajax(
        {
        type        : "GET",
        url         : processURL,
        cache       : false,
        dataType    : "json",
        success     : function (d) 
            {           
            var oTable = $('#Test').dataTable();
            oTable.fnDestroy();
            $('#Test').dataTable(
                        {
                        "sScrollY": "200px",
                        "bPaginate": false,
                        "sDom": "frtiS",
                        "bDeferRender": true,
                        "aaSorting": [[ 1, "asc" ]],
                        "aaData": d,
                        "aoColumns":    
                            [
                            { "mData": "N1" },
                            { "mData": "N2" },
                            { "mData": "3" },
                            { "mData": "STR" },
                            { "mData": "PLZ" },
                            { "mData": "ORT" },
                            { "mData": "ID" }                                                               
                            ],
                        "aoColumnDefs": 
                            [ 
                                { 
                                "sClass": "hide_me", "aTargets": [ 6 ]
                                } 
                            ]
                        });             
            var oTable1 = $('#Test').dataTable();
            oTable1.fnStandingRedraw();               
            }, 
        error : function (d) 
            {                       
            alert('Error');
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: please elaborate the problem

Comment: Sorry, I added the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
$("td:contains(text)");
```

Comment: Thanks, with an variable it works for me ;-)

Comment: Here is the Code:       var x = "Telefon";
$( "tr:contains('" + x + "')").css( "background-color", "red" );

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you can use: jQuery( ":contains(text)" ). Take a look at this http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/

Answer (score 0):

Search for a string in table cell using `find()`: if it finds it, then add the class to parent.

```
$("table tr td").find("something").parent().addClass('parentCell');
```